# select- option in different colors

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
if($zsubedurum==0){ $subextext = 'Kapalı'; $subexrenk = '#d00000'; $disabled='disabled="disabled"'; } 
                                        if($zsubedurum==1){ $subextext = 'Aktif'; $subexrenk = 'green'; $disabled=''; } 
                                        if($zsubedurum==2){ $subextext = 'Yoğun'; $subexrenk = '#ff9300'; $disabled=''; }

                                        echo '<option value="'.$subesecid.'" '.$disabled.'>'.$subesecname.' - <span style="color:'.$subexrenk.'">'.$subextext.'</span></option>';
```

I'm trying to do something like this but its not working how can I do this?

Comment: Is it actually PHP code? You tagged only JavaScript in your question.

Comment: yeah I know but nothing wrong with the PHP code and I add like PHP code cause you can understand how it works my system...

Comment: Not working means what? You don't see the options or just problem with colors?

Comment: Just colors.. span code dont work